# Building blocks of particles in different theories

Tags: particle-physics, models, point-particles

If I understand it correctly, in most theories in physics we exploit the notion of point, i.e. we have e.g. point-like particles. In string theory, we don't have points, but a notion of string. What are other models of particles?

Comment: The idea of a particle as an infinitesimally small dot is not a good description. Particles are described as excitations in a quantum field. They are point like in the sense that by going to arbitrarily high energies the particle can be resolved with arbitrarily great precision, but this does not mean quantum field theory models them as points.

Comment: So, we use the notion of excitation (feature in model selection) for describing particles. Can we talk about excitation at the macro-scale?

Comment: You'll have to clarify what *excitation at the macro-scale* means.

Comment: This was exactly my second question. Is this notion (excitation) used also at the macro-scale, i.e. can we, for instance, use for describing the motion of planets?

Comment: No. The concept is specific to quantum fields. The motion of planets is described by a classical field and this is **completely** different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical physics describes the movement of the center of gravity of extended bodies, which, when poorly taught, in the mind of the student becomes equivalent with "classical physics being a theory of point particles". That, of course, is utterly false, even on the level of the classical description. A center of gravity is a vector, not a point. Mathematically we never talk about the dynamic of "a point". Instead we are investigating the dynamic of an equivalence class of position vectors that are all linked by Galilean transformations.

A good classical mechanics textbook will make this very clear. Landau and Lifshitz found it so important, that they made it the center of the very first few sentences of their volume on mechanics!

Because the center of mass is merely a simplification (almost ad absurdum) in classical mechanics, it is perfectly capable of describing extended bodies. We have very good dynamic formulas for the movement of extended rigid bodies using virtual forces, and there is a complex theory of classic rotation (the chaotic motion of the asymmetric top is still a matter of investigation). Going beyond rigid bodies we have a good theory of elastic bodies and different levels of the description of liquids and gases.

That we are teaching about the movement of "point particles" in the first lessons about physics to students is an unfortunate side effect of the fact that the treatment of equations of motion of extended bodies requires complex mathematical tools that can deal with the necessary scalar density and vectorial and tensorial force fields, which beginning students simply can't master. We are not teaching it because there is something fundamental about "points". Indeed, it's a much more consistent strategy to go from extended bodies to idealized center of mass movement than to pretend that somehow an extended body is made up of an infinity of point masses.

Going beyond classical mechanics we keep encountering that fields are the natural way of describing nature in electrodynamics and quantum mechanics. The difference between "point particle" and "strings" in quantum field theory is the dimensionality of the fundamental interactions in these fields, which is zero-dimensional and one dimensional.

Comment: Before I mark this as an answer, could you please clarify the notion of interaction. From what I understand, we often think of forces that they their carriers. Is this big word "interaction" connected with force and how do we model it?

Comment: By interaction I mean the form of the Lagrangian in the field theory. I am not a theorist, but it is my understanding that in string theory it takes the form of a line integral, whereas in "point" QFT it is a function of point coordinates. That leads to hard to control divergences in "point particle" QFT, whereas string theory is more forgiving and it should produce fewer un-physical mathematical artifacts that have to be dealt with trough normalization procedures. Particles arise from this only trough the quantization of the field and one can have an argument over their "reality".

Comment: Thank you, CuriousOne, will have to take a much closer look at the model of interaction and particle.